# Is there any way to track the creation of element with document.createElement()?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, mutation-observers

Is there any way to catch the `document.createElement()` event?

For example, somewhere, inside the `<body>` section I have

```html
<script>
    var div = document.createElement("div");
<script>
```

Is it possible to track that event from the `<head>` section (using some addEventListener, mutation observer, or any other way)?

**Note:** I need to track the **creation** of the element, **not the insertion**

Comment: There is hardly a reason to have such an event in the DOM. What would you need this for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Warning* This code won't work in every browser. All bets are off when it comes to IE.

```
(function() {
  // Step1: Save a reference to old createElement so we can call it later.
  var oldCreate = document.createElement;

  // Step 2: Create a new function that intercepts the createElement call
  // and logs it.  You can do whatever else you need to do.
  var create = function(type) {
    console.log("Creating: " + type);
    return oldCreate.call(document, type);
  }

  // Step 3: Replace document.createElement with our custom call.
  document.createElement = create;

}());
```

Comment: And capturing/showing the creation event..? Am I missing that part? I see the `console.log()`, but I was expecting an actual JavaScript event, somehow.

Comment: Better comments there.

Comment: @DavidThomas: There is no such event.

Comment: @Bergi: I'm aware of that, which is why this question exists, surely?

Comment: well you can create events for yourself..check out my answer

Answer (score 2):

This is, similarly to other answers, an imperfect and incomplete solution (and is explicitly tested in *only* Chrome 34 on Windows 8.1):

```
// creating a function to act as a wrapper to document.createElement:
document.create = function(elType){
    // creating the new element:
    var elem = document.createElement(elType),
        // creating a custom event (called 'elementCreated'):
        evt = new CustomEvent('elementCreated', {
            // details of the custom event:
            'detail' : {
                // what was created:
                'elementType' : elem.tagName,
                // a reference to the created node:
                'elementNode' : elem
            }
    });
    // dispatching the event:
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);

    // returning the created element:
    return elem;
};

// assigning an event-handler to listen for the 'elementCreated' event:
document.addEventListener('elementCreated', function(e){
    // react as you like to the creation of a new element (using 'document.create()'):
    console.log(e);
});

// creating a new element using the above function:
var newDiv = document.create('div');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cXJzz/).

References:

- [Creating and triggering events (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create custom Events in javascript. And it's supported by all browsers too.

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/JZwB4/1/

```
document.createElement = (function(){
    var orig = document.createElement;
    var event = new CustomEvent("elemCreated");
    return function() { 
        document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
        orig.call(document,x); 
    };
})();


document.body.addEventListener('elemCreated', function(){
    console.log('created');
},false);

var x= document.createElement('p'); //"created" in console
```